# Composer Downloader Exception, Configuration does not allow to connect

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I want to install Laravel by composer in Windows, I installed composer with setup and disabled **tls** by below command:

```
composer config -g -- disable-tls true
```

When I run the Laravel installation command (`composer global require "laravel/installer"`) or any composer command that need to send some request to composer server, like `composer self-update`, this bellow error appear!

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Your configuration does not
>   allow connections to http://getcomposer.org/versions. See
>   https:getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.

Comment: why did you disable-tls? this means, that your composer always tries http instead of https urls. but by default composer only allows https urls, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#disable-tls 
https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http
either set disable-tls to false again or set secure-http to false

Comment: I disable tls because of openssl extension error in php. even when I enable this extension in php.ini file.